# Pycharm doesn't copy root folder to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm community edition 2017.3 in Windows 10.
I'm running Python 2.7 with venv.

Till today all was good, but all of a sudden, PyCharm stopped adding the root folder to PYTHON path, and things stopped working (unless I add it manually to sys.path). I haven't change anything in the PyCharm configuration (at least not explicitly...). I tried closing and reopening PyCharm, reboot, clear the cache, cleaning Python compiled files, setting the root folder as 'sources root', but none seems to work.

The same code exactly is deployed on another computer and it's working.

This is the bad line:

```
from TM2_VAL_LAB import test_base, robot_handler
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/baruchl/Documents/_GIT/TM2_VAL_LAB/TM2_VAL_LAB/test_vr_translation_ff.py", line 17, in <module>
    from TM2_VAL_LAB import test_base, robot_handler
ImportError: No module named TM2_VAL_LAB
```

When I run the following during the python execution:

```
print os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')
```

I get:

```
None
```

When I run the same code in the remote computer (where everything running smoothly), I get:

```
C:\GIT\TM2_VAL_LAB
```

which is the root folder of the python script I'm running.

This is the run configuration I'm using:
[image]

This is how my project looks like:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few back and forth with PyCharm rep, the solution is to close PyCharm, rename/delete the .idea folder and re-open PyCharm.
That's it.

After this, when when running the same file as before,

```
print os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')
```

results in:

```
C:\Users\baruchl\Documents\_GIT\TM2_VAL_LAB
```

and

```
print sys.path
```

results in:

```
['C:\\Users\\baruchl\\Documents\\_GIT\\TM2_VAL_LAB\\TM2_VAL_LAB', 'C:\\Users\\baruchl\\Documents\\_GIT\\TM2_VAL_LAB', ...]
```